# pass map key attribute from servlet to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

I want to get name of employee in a LinkedHashMap key from servlet to jsp.

I have this code in java class View.java

```
LinkedHashMap<Employee, LinkedHashMap<Skill, String>>() employeeSkills = new LinkedHashMap<Employee, LinkedHashMap<Skill, String>>();
```

Class View has setters and getters for employeeSkills.

Class Employee has name and id attributes with setters and getters.

JSP Code:

```
< c:forEach var="employeeSkills" items="${employeeSkills}" >
    <td>${employeeSkills.key.name}</td>
</c:forEach>
```

but i get this error

> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'name' not readable on type java.lang.String

Employee Class:

```
    class Employee{
    String id;
    String name;
    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Employee(String id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }


}
```

Comment: I don't know why do you need beans.

Comment: I am working on a big project and they are already beans I want to have a data structure where each employee has several skills is there a better structure ?

Comment: Then associate em to employee object.

Comment: Can you show the code for the `Employee` class?

Comment: How do you pass your Map to your JSP?

Comment: I pass it using struts2 framework. I found the problem was to make the  employee class public. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (call `var` differently):

```
<c:forEach var="emplSkill" items="${employeeSkills}" >
    <td>${emplSkill.key.name}</td>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: output is employee object also > ViewAction$Employee@20af022

Comment: @AhmedSoliman With the above code, output is `ViewAction$Employee@20af022`? You're sure you well copied-pasted the snippet?

Comment: This was the output >View$Employee@20af022. I found the problem was to make the employee class public. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

remove the .name and you're fine

Comment: this returns an employee object I want its name

Comment: whats the jsp output?

Comment: output when removing .name
> ViewAction$Employee@20af022

Answer (score 0):

Make class employee public
then the jsp works perfect

Comment: always make model classes public! Without public, the default visibility is just in the package